# C# Binary Decoder based on XML specification

Tags: c#, xml, file, binary, decoding

I want to develop decoder in .net C# for one binary file.

Can you please give me some directions (I know that question is general and not code specific)

So here is catch:

1. There is XML schema (with syntax) for XML file
2. XML file based on XML schema contains descriptions (names etc) of parameters and my encoded file have values for that parameters.
3. There is also another XML for enumeration of some of values from binary file.
4. So there is two XML file and one XML schema (Input to application will be only XML files and binary file)

EDIT:

Binary file have this format:
HEADER, Event 1, Event N, Error X, Event N + 1, Event M, FOOTER

And XML file specifies how the information is structured in the binary files.

So, what is (known) technique or best practice for this kind of problem? DO you have any general instruction? Is there any classes (in .net or open source assemblies) for this kind of decoding etc.

BR

Comment: So what do you actually want to do? check an xml file against a schema?

Comment: No. I want decode binary file. Put values in data structure. Binary file is define with xml document. That means that in xml we have structure (description of parameters, names etc) and binary file contain only values. I'll update question with examples.

Comment: show a XML example file

Comment: did you come across any useful advice/existing projects? I am looking for one too. I need to use a file that both a C# project as well as an android module can parse/write, I am not looking for a specific C#-Android data transfer solution, but a general binary parser/writer based on XML specification.